# Ubuntu 22.10 + pipenv + PyCharm Community Edition

Tags: ubuntu, pycharm, pipenv

Всем привет!

Для уже существующего проекта, стянутого с gitlab, пытаюсь выставить в PyCharm интерпретатор Python отличный от дефолтного (3.6) в Ubuntu 22.10 (3.10)
Выставляю в разделе pipenv этот 3.6, PyCharm пытается развернуть виртуалку и падает с ошибкой установки пакетов (на втором скрине). В путях видно, что он пытается это сделать почему-то через 3.10 версию. Если попытаться выставить 3.6 через "System Interpeter", то всё отрабатывает нормально...наверное...
Он выставляет для проекта 3.6, при том оставляя в "System Interpeter" 3.10...
Фишка в том, что фз как это будет работать не для одного, а многих проектов, где нужно нормально указать версию Python для проекта через pipenv в PyCharm.

Мб кто сталкивался с таким бредом
PyCharm и pipenv вот прям сегодня стягивались при установке - свежее всё.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В общем, не парьте мозг... Просто поставьте 22.04 или пониже 20.04